# Windows Application start me console

Tags: c++, console, windows

today i compiled my c++ Windows app and it have started console and the app but the console never appeared before.Can someone tell me how to remove the console ?

Comment: Is the compiler for Dev C++ mingw? If so perhaps that should be added to the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if your linker settings have /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE. Change that to /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Or open the property page of your executable and update Linker/System/Subsystem to Windows.

Edit: Now that you specify you are not using Visual Studio I know that the property page will not help. I am not sure if Dev C++ is using mingw although even if it was I could not help finding how to fix the linker setting anyways since I do not use mingw either..

Comment: im using the default compiler

Comment: From the web page: http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html it says that the compiler is mingw.

Answer (score 1):

For `mingw` compiler you should pass `-subsystem windows` to linker like

```
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows <other linker options>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was some bug i just restarted the Dev C++ and its fixed also i deleted some files from the app and i think they can be the problem because i had 2 empty .rc files.So if someone is having this problem to try looking in the trash and to restart the app